# Cursor on table type in Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, cursor

I have a table declaration:

```
TYPE PERSON_TYPE AS OBJECT (ID NUMBER(38), NAME VARCHAR2(20));
TYPE PERSON_TYPE_TABLE AS TABLE OF PERSON_TYPE;
```

Can I declare cursor which will be work with my table type in Oracle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE
        p PERSON_TYPE_TABLE := PERSON_TYPE_TABLE(PERSON_TYPE(1, 'test'));
        id INT;
        name VARCHAR2(100);
        CURSOR mycur
        IS
        SELECT  *
        FROM    TABLE(p);
BEGIN
        OPEN    mycur;
        FETCH   mycur
        INTO    id, name;
        CLOSE   mycur;
END;
```